# Do shopify App need hosting?

Tags: hosting, shopify, shopify-app

I'm developing a shopify app, wondering whether I need additional hosting for the app separately after install.

Can I do some sort of UI injection to shopify admin view and storefront?

Comment: This is a question that you should forward to Shopify support since this is not code related. To answer you question, yes you need separate hosting.

Comment: Thank you! Already asked from Shopify support, guess they don't have an exact idea. Some said no need of such hosting, while some said requires hosting. Since got no help by asking, that's why posted here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you'll need hosting. Most partners use heroku.com , digitalocean.com or amazon web service.

You can inject into the Shopify admin using the embedded app sdk.

https://help.shopify.com/api/sdks/shopify-apps/embedded-app-sdk

Answer (score -1):

Shopify app needs hosting  to inject the code into shopify admin using embedded app sdk